# Store an array of SDL_Surface items in a class?

Tags: c++, arrays, sdl, dynamic-arrays

I want to store all my SDL_Surface variables in an array, and to hold that array in a class. The reason is that I want to be able to reload all SDL_Surfaces based on events.

I think it should be something like this, I'm probably wrong though:

```
class Imgs_Arr{
    private:
        int pos;
    public:
        // DECLARE THE ARRAY 
        Imgs_Arr();
        void addItem(char * path);
        void changeItem(int pos);
};

Imgs_Arr::Imgs_Arr(){
    // CREATE ARRAY 
}

void Imgs_Arr::addItem(char * path){ // ADD ITEM IN LAST ARRAY POSITION
    vec[pos] = load_image(path);
    if( vec[pos] == NULL ) exit(5);
    pos++;
}

void Imgs_Arr::changeItem(int p){ // ADD ITEM IN LAST ARRAY POSITION
    vec[p] = load_image(path);
    if( vec[p] == NULL ) exit(5);
}
```

I'm looking for an example of how to do it. But any information will be useful. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that `SDL_Surface` pointers are just opaque handles. There are no real `SDL_Surface` *objects* that you are allowed to know about.

Comment: the problem is that I need to iterate through all my SDL_Surface items to scale them on window resize. So I thought the best way was to store them all in an array, isn't there any way to do this?

Comment: my question was completely wrong, I corrected it now to point more clearly to my intentions instead of how I thought it should be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is somewhat specific, since `SDL_Surface*` is an opaque handle. You must never know the actual `SDL_Surface` *object* which it points to. So, you need a dynamic array of opaque handles. For the main array, we just use `std::vector`, so I'd do it like this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <SDL.h>

class Arr_Images
{
    using sdl_handle = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, void(*)(SDL_Surface*)>;

    sdl_handle wrap_unique_surface(SDL_Surface * s)
    {
        return sdl_handle(s, SDL_FreeSurface);
    }

    std::vector<sdl_handle> surfaces;

public:
    void addImg(char const * path)
    {
        if (SDL_Surface * p = load_image(path))
        {
            surfaces.push_back(wrap_unique_surface(p));
        } 
        else
        {
            // failed to load
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: See the updated question, I don't care about how to implement it

Comment: @Liso22: I updated my question with what I think would be a generally sane approach. You can change an individual, existing surace with something like `surfaces[3].reset(q);`, where `q` is another raw `SDL_Surface *`.

Comment: great thanks, I included memory and vector (sdl was already loaded) and tested it. I got this message: "expected nested-name-identifier in sdl_handle". Should I replace sdl_handle with something?

Comment: You need C++11 for `unique_ptr`. If your compiler doesn't support `using`, you can also say `typedef std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, void(*)(SDL_Surface*)> sdl_handle;`.

Comment: thanks, I got it to work. Just one more question, how do I return an SDL_Image from a method?

Comment: @Liso22: Like `surfaces[i].get()` I suppose, though `unique_ptr` overloads the `->` operator, so you can do many things direcly as `surfaces[i]->...`.